# Code running in MARS but not QTSims

Tags: mips, mars-simulator, qtspim

I have this program written that is running perfectly on MARS, but when i use QTSIMS to load it, it stops working and returns a zero for every calculation, can someone tell me why?

I'm not sure about the difference between the two to be honest.

```
.globl main
```

main:

```
.text

li $v0, 4   # print string
la $a0, large   # load string
syscall

li $v0, 5       # prompt for integer
syscall
move $s0, $v0   # store input

#Below is the same but different strings and inputs

li $v0, 4
la $a0, largepicked
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, small
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s2, $v0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, smallpicked
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s3, $v0
```

## calculate factorials

```
move $a0, $s0           # save large value to function
move $a1, $s1           # save small value to function
jal factmod             # compute factorial of (large!/small!)
move $s4, $v0           # store value

move $a0, $s1           # save small value to original factorial
jal factrl          # compute factorial
move $s5, $v0           # store value

#Repeat for second lottery
move $a0, $s2
move $a1, $s3
jal factmod
move $s6, $v0

move $a0, $s3
jal factrl
move $s7, $v0
```

## calculate the odds

```
div $s4, $s5
mflo $s4

div $s6, $s7
mflo $s6

mul $s4, $s4, $s6
```

## print result to console

```
li $v0, 4
la $a0, result
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, stopped
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Normal factorial code

```
factrl: sw $ra, 4($sp)      # save the return address
sw $a0, 0($sp)      # save the current value of n
addi $sp, $sp, -8   # move stack pointer
slti $t0, $a0, 2    # save 1 iteration, n=0 or n=1; n!=1
beq $t0, $zero, L1  # not less than 2, calculate n(n-1)!
addi $v0, $zero, 1  # n=1; n!=1
jr $ra          # now multiply

L1:     addi $a0, $a0, -1   # n = n-1
jal factrl      # now (n-1)!
addi $sp, $sp, 8    # reset the stack pointer
lw $a0, 0($sp)      # fetch saved (n-1)
lw $ra, 4($sp)      # fetch return address
mul $v0, $a0, $v0   # multiply (n)*(n-1)
jr $ra          # return value n!
```

factorial of large!/small!

```
factmod: sw $ra, 8($sp)          # save the return address
sw $a0, 4($sp)          # save the value of large
sw $a1, 0($sp)          # save the value of small

addi $t0, $zero, 1      # set counter
lw $t1, 4($sp)          # set large
lw $t2, 0($sp)          # set small
move $v0, $t1           # set large as the numerator

loop:   addi $t0, $t0, 1        # increment counter
addi $t1, $t1, -1       # decrement large
mul $v0, $t1, $v0       # large * large - 1
    bge  $t0, $t2, done # if counter less  than small, loop
    j loop

done:   lw $ra, 8($sp)          # fetch return address
jr $ra          # return value
```

.data

```
large:          .asciiz "Please enter the number of balls in the large pool: "
largepicked:    .asciiz "Please enter the number of balls picked from the large pool: "
small:          .asciiz "Please enter the number of balls in the second pool: "
smallpicked:    .asciiz "Please enter the number of balls picked from the second pool: "
result:     .asciiz "The odds are 1 in "

stopped:        .asciiz "\nStopped"
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i used another computer to run QtSpim and it worked